# Filtering SharePoint List in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

In SharePoint 2010,
I have inserted Html Form web part to filter my SharePoint list items. When I press **GO** Button with any of the keywords it will display the items in the list, but when I try to clear the filter or else search with empty keywords it displays **No Data** in the list.

Please Help me,
Actually I want search button with text field to display the items in my SharePoint list. If you have any other web parts can you please help  me out to display the search items in web page.

Comment: Can you update your question with the html code that you use in the Html form web part? This might help to find the issue and its possible fix.

Comment: Yeah Okay Ahmad Zia, Next time i'll update with the screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div onkeydown="T1keydown()">
  <input type="text" name="T1" id="T1T1"/>
  <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="T1apply()"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">

function T1keydown() {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) 
    T1apply();
}

function T1apply() {
  var text = document.getElementById("T1T1").value;
  if (text.length > 0) 
  {
    _SFSUBMIT_;
    return;
  }
  window.location.href=window.location.href;
}

  </script>
</div>
```

This code will clear all filters.

**OR**

Go for SharePoint Designer and create parameters and add connection to the web part. When you create parameters then you can connect multiple columns in the list. And it will automatically clear all filters.

Comment: Actually this code was works only when the webpart doesn't have permission to open in SharePoint Designer. Then this code can be used in HTML Form web part's source code it will applies only when the search for empty value then the filter shows **no data** in List/Library. And also it will works only one single columns to filter.

Comment: Need to filter Multiple columns then insert **HTML Form web part** and give connection to one column and go to **SPD** and create parameter then add connection with **Filter values with parameters**, by this it will filter multiple columns.